# required type List provided UniformTile

Tags: java

I keep getting error on RandomUniformGenerator method that made the tile attribute so that it corresponds to the list of tiles of the requested colors but it tell me provided UniformTile instead of List , but List is abstract and can't be instantiated. need help with this one :/

```
package model;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomUniformTileGenerator implements TileGenerator{
    private final List<Tile> tiles;
    private final Random randomGenerator;


    public RandomUniformTileGenerator(List<Color> colors, Random randomGenerator){
        this.tiles = new UniformTile(new ColoredSide(colors.get(colors.size()))) ;
        this.randomGenerator = randomGenerator;
    }
    public Tile nextTile(Square square){
        return this.tiles.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(tiles.size()));
    }
}
```

// Tile generator

```
package model;

public interface TileGenerator {
    Tile nextTile(Square square);
   }
```

// UniformTile

```
package model;

public class UniformTile implements Tile{
    private final Side side;

    public UniformTile(Side side) {
        this.side = side;
    }
    public Side side(CardinalDirection direction){
        return side;
    }
}
```

// ColorSide

```
package model;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import model.Side;

public class ColoredSide implements Side {
    private final Color color;
    public ColoredSide(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Color color() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

// Side
package model;

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.util.List;

public interface Side {
  Color color();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` is just a interface and specifies the methods a class must implement. A implementation of `List` would be `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. So in your example you would want something like:

```
private final List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList()<>;
```

We initialize the variable `tiles` as `ArrayList`, but the actual implementation is hidden behind the `List` declaration.

Instead of writing `List<Tile>` =`UniformTile` you probably want to `add` your tile to the List of `tiles`.

```
tiles.add(new UniformTile(new ColoredSide(colors.get(colors.size()))));
```

Comment: tiles.add() method returns void/boolean

Comment: Yes and if you want to get an element out of the list you can use `tiles.get(index)`.